# How to rollback the data in mysql server

Tags: mysql, rollback

How to roll back old database after importing new script in it.

I have imported a script over my existing database.
Now I want to rollback my latest import and want to get the previous database as such.
Is there any possibility to get my previous database values with date and timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

Once an update is committed you can't rollback just the single update. Your best bet is to roll back to a previous backup of the database.
And if you don't have backup file for your database then you need to use APEX Sql Data Driven.

You need this tool and you can find the transaction and reverse it.

ApexSQL Log

Comment: Can u please elaborate Apex SQL.